# Active file sync in Linux

Tags: software-recommendation, files, gui

So, I've looked at a lot of file syncing tools out there: Syncthing, Rsync, Grsync, FreeFileSync, and nothing is exactly what I am looking for.

When I used to run Windows I used GoodSync. What I liked about GoodSync is you could hit "analyze" and it would show you what it is about to do. If there were files that were going the wrong direction for some reason, you could select and override this before you executed the sync. This was very useful as it was syncing a local/remote folder. It also kept "backups" in separate folders just in case you did something that was not indented. It was a perfect tool for what I needed. Is there anything similar on linux?

Thanks,
CJ

Comment: How do we know what you are looking for? There is a ton of ways to setup sync on linux.

Comment: I use LuckyBackup available from the USC repositories and that utility is a splendid front end to Rsync which allows you to perform a dry run first if required.

Comment: User24601 - Thanks for the input. I will check out LuckyBackup. I am looking for something that I can have full control over a backup. Meaning, that if the backup system analyzes the system, I can review what it is going to do and intervene with those actions if I need to. I want something steamlined with a GUI. I am looking for something comparable to GoodSync for windows.

Comment: I looked into LuckyBackup. I like it, however, it shows me a bunch of output that is is about to do but it doesn't tell me in which direction the files are moving. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think FreeFileSync is the most comparable to what I am looking for. Not sure why I wrote that is wasn't an alternative back then. Maybe because I could not get the GUI part of it to work on my system?